# Can I get an image from a website i don't own using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I would like to get another website DOM and search through it for an image to download but this gives me CORS policy errors and i would like to know some other way to do it

```js
  $.get({
    url: "https://www.example.com",
    method: "get",
    success: function(data) {
      var html = $.parseHTML(data),
        img = $(html).find("img"),
        len = img.length;
      if (len > 0) {
        var src = img.attr("src");
      } else {
        console.log("Image not found");
      }
      console.log(src);
    }
  });
```

---

### Original Post:

I would like to download an image from another website (which I do not own), I can view this website and said image publicly, however trying to do a `$.get()` with the URL gives me a CORS policy error, is there no way to actually do this?

Comment: No, it's not possible to do this in client-side JS unless the third-party site includes CORS headers in the response. Given the error you state, they have not done this. The work around is to do it server side instead

Comment: so.... how would I do that?

Comment: That entirely depends on what server side platform you're using

Answer (score 0):

You can send a request with [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) on the server. Or, you can use some programming language that you use (and didn't specify in your question) to send a request. Example:

```
<?php
$img[]='http://images.rottentomatoescdn.com/images/redesign/poster_default.gif';

foreach($img as $i){
echo $i;
    save_image($i);
    // if(getimagesize(basename($i))){
        // echo '<h3 style="color: green;">Image ' . basename($i) . ' Downloaded OK</h3>';
    // }else{
        // echo '<h3 style="color: red;">Image ' . basename($i) . ' Download Failed</h3>';
    // }
}

//Alternative Image Saving Using cURL seeing as allow_url_fopen is disabled - bummer
function save_image($img,$fullpath='basename'){
    if($fullpath=='basename'){
        $fullpath = basename($img);
    }
    $ch = curl_init ($img);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($fullpath)){
        unlink($fullpath);
    }
    $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Taken from here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Comment: Right, that's cool and all but how do I actually get the image URL?
My question was probably worded wrongly lol.

The code that's giving me CORS errors goes something like this:
```
  $.get({
    url: "url",
    success: function(data) {
      var html = $.parseHTML(data),
        img = $(html).find("article.comic img, article.comic * img"),
        len = img.length;
      if (len > 0) {
        var src = img.attr("src"); // get src of image
      console.log(src);
    }
  });
```

I'm trying to actually get the DOM of that other website and search through it to find the img.

Comment: @Vawlpe you can send a GET request to the other site and render it as part of a page in your project, but putting the following Javascript into the body of the page: ```alert([...document.querySelectorAll('img').values()].map((img) => img.src).join(', '))```. This will alert all the locations of all images on the page, separated by comma.